# Best Database to use with WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid

I am starting on creating a WPF application that uses the Datagrid.  I need to design my database before I go any further, however, I am not sure which database is the best solution.  I am developing in Visual Studio 2010 using C# and Xaml.  The user will be entering data, modifying data, and deleting data.  They will also need to create reports of the data.  Is there any database that integrates well with VS 2010, C#, .Net 4.0, and WPF's Datagrid?

Comment: I would let the data schema and deployment requirements dictate my database engine choice, not my UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 R2, is your best choice for rapid integration with WPF. (There is some debate, based on the actual needs of your data, if SQL Server will be the best overall choice).

This will give you access to the Entity Framework to pair with SQL, making it much easier to manage your CRUD operations. Here is an article to get you started with EF, and SQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723

Comment: Thanks!  This will help me alot!

Comment: YW. While UI integration is not the only reason to choose a DB platform, it is one valid reason to do so. It's worth noting the other answers as well, since you will want to ensure that your data-schema is suitable for SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

If you are choosing your database based on the type of UI components you will be using on the front-end, you will be making the decision for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There are many DBs that integrate with WPF DataGrids; SQL Server CE, SQL Server Express, mySQL, Postgresql, Oracle. It is not evident from your question why you need a SQL database, or even a database at all. You can bind datagrids to XML, flat files, or even .Net classes.

A general principle is that if there are many solutions to a problem, that is because there is no one "best" solution; each solution has its own benefits and disadvantages. Which one is best for you depends on exactly what you are doing, which you have not told us.

You need to explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish; what kind of "data" will users be entering? How much? Do you need multi-threaded access? Multi-application? Multi-user? Cross-machine? Cross-internet? Disconnected?

How will users be installing this application? Does it need to run under restricted accounts? Does it need to interoperate with other applications?

Until we have answers to these questions it would be irresponsible to suggest a database.